# Is there a height requirement for hot/cold washing machine supplies

Tags: plumbing, water, water-pressure, washing-machine

Is there a minimum height requirement for the hot/cold water supplies for my washing machine?

I know there are strict requirements for the drainage (i.e: the standpipe) but I could not find anything for the supplies.

I basically want my supply lines to be hooked up under my utility sink (so to the side/middle of my washing machine).

Are there any height requirements? Do the supply lines have to be located above the washing machine? Or can I can I get away with having them go underneath my utility sink.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As supplies can come down from the ceiling or up from the floor then just at an easily reached height...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the supply line it is recommended you have easy access to the shutoff valve in case the washer's valve fails leading to a flood from the machine.

There is no height requirement for the supply.

So if you are placing the supply under the sink, perhaps in a cabinet, make sure it is easily accessible and make sure the operator (spouse, tenant, in-law) knows the shut off is there.

The drain, however, has a maximum height requirement stipulated by the machine's manufacturer, as the lift height is limited by the drain pump's power. Usually a machine's pump can drain to about 41in so that it can drain into a nearby sink, often at about 36in height.

For practical reasons, the drain and supply for an in-wall installation are provided in one "washing machine outlet box" in the laundry room, and so the supply ends up at the same height as the drain. The outlet box is installed behind the washer and just above it so that it can be easily reached for shut off. This height is about 41in from the floor.